# python selenium if condition based on text inside span-strong

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 different text inside `"/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong"` based on the input it will appear 2 different text

```
text_strong_1 = "Your video has submitted successfully"

text_strong_2 = "This video title has already been chosen - Please input unique video title"
```

i tried with this condition

```
elem_wait = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong")), text_strong_2)
if elem_wait:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

so the result of the input is `text_strong_1`, but the if condition based on is `text_strong_2`, it should print "Wrong", but instead it print "True".

should i use `visibility_of_element_located or text_to_be_present_in_element`?

here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zephyr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Zephyr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", 
line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", 
line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\Zephyr\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "e:\Coding Space\Adclick\adclick.py", line 145, in <module>
    input_data()
  File "e:\Coding Space\Adclick\adclick.py", line 114, in input_data
    elem_wait = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong[text()='This Video Title has already been chosen - please choose a unique title that best describes the content of the video.']")))   
  File "C:\Users\Zephyr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, 
in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

Comment: you can change the xpath to  include text also `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong[text()='Your video has submitted successfully']"))`

Comment: but when the text inside the strong is not text_strong_2 it would not print "Wrong" instead it become error and the script is shutdown

Comment: can you post the error in the post

Comment: yes, already posted it

Comment: you can use `EC.any_of()` add two xpaths and after finding the element just compare the text

Comment: compare? can u give me an example? i know how to use EC.any_of() but i dont know how to compare the text

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
element1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Your video has submitted successfully')]")
element2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'This video title has already been chosen - Please input unique video title')]")

if len(element1) > 0:
    print("element 1 exists")

if len(element2) > 0:
    print("element 2 exists")
```

NOTE: Notice I have used `find_elements` and not `find_element`. This will ensure you will not get `no such element exeception`

**UPDATE:** Similar solution but using selenium's `waits`. Try the below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
element1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Your video has submitted successfully')]")))
element2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'This video title has already been chosen - Please input unique video title')]")))

if len(element1) > 0:
    print("element 1 exists")

if len(element2) > 0:
    print("element 2 exists")
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: yeah this give me error

Comment: What error did you get? Can you share the error trace?

Comment: sorry not an error, but the result of print is not appear. i think the condition isn't met and the code decide to skip it

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. Let me know it that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EC.any_of()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.any_of) like this, It will return first matched element, then you can just use text attribute to compare

```
text_strong_1 = "Your video has submitted successfully"
text_strong_2 = "This video title has already been chosen - Please input unique video title"

cond1 = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong[text()='{text_strong_1}']"))
cond2 = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[10]/span/strong[text()='{text_strong_2}']"))

element = EC.any_of(cond1, cond2)

print('True' if element.text == text_strong_1 else 'Wrong')
```